# How to get sum of all the digits in a string - Visual Basic 2010 (Module)

Tags: vb.net, string

How do I get the sum of all the digits in a string, in visual basic?

---For example---

```
Dim userWord As String
userWord = Console.ReadLine()
```

User Input: "Fox jumped over the 12 moon"

Output Display: 3

Comment: (Sorry, getting used to this whole formatting thing in website)

'Dim userWord As String
Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence, so the program can play around with it.")
Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to end the program")
userWord = Console.ReadLine()

Console.WriteLine("Sum of all digits in the String: ")
//this is the part where I am stuck


 Dim num As Char() = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim total As Integer

            If (Integer.TryParse(num, i)) Then
                Console.WriteLine(total = i + i)
            End If'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What jereon said:

```
    Dim mytext As String = "123a123"
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each ch As Char In mytext
        Dim i As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(ch, i) Then
            sum += i
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: +1 - I tested this one works.. I realized Convert.ToInt32 is not the way to go.

Comment: indeed, but i rather didn't suply the working code because this was probably a school assignment :p

Answer (score 2):

1. loop over your chars in your string with a foreach
2. TryParse them to an int
3. Keep a variable that has the total and add if it is an integer

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dim mytext As String = "Fox jumped over the 12 moon"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each ch As Char In mytext
         Dim temp As Integer = 0
         If Integer.TryParse(ch, temp) Then
              i += temp;
         End If
    Next
```

Comment: Here is what I have in my code so far:

' 
Dim userWord As String


Dim myChars() As Char = userWord.ToCharArray()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each ch As Char In myChars
                If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                    i += Convert.ToInt32(ch)
                End If
            Next

Console.WriteLine("Sum of all digits in the String: ")
            Console.WriteLine(i)

'
User Input: Fox12
Output: 99

I want the output to be 3 (1 + 2 = 3). Could you go into detail how 1 + 2 = 99? Am I missing something?

Comment: put a break point & debug. See if Char.IsDigit(ch) is true on 2 occasions

Comment: This does not work.  How did it get two upvotes?  The problem is not understanding Convert.ToInt32

Comment: @dbasnett :  please try now

Comment: @dumass I see you fixed it, and it looks a lot like the code I posted.  Dim myChars() As Char = mytext.ToCharArray() is not needed.

Comment: @Matt - I'd rather want you to mark dbasnett's as answer below as he corrected mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq

```
Dim input As String = "Fox jumped over the 12 moon"
Dim sum As Integer = input.Where(Function(c) [Char].IsDigit(c))
                          .Sum(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.ToString()))
```

This extracts all the chars that are digits (`[Char].IsDigit]`) and then converts those chars to integers (`Integer.Parse`) whilst summing them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have in my code so far:

```
    Dim userWord As String


    Dim myChars() As Char = userWord.ToCharArray()
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each ch As Char In myChars
                    If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                        i += Convert.ToInt32(ch)
                    End If
                Next

    Console.WriteLine("Sum of all digits in the String: ")
                Console.WriteLine(i)
```

User Input: Fox12
Output: 99

I want the output to be 3 (1 + 2 = 3). Could you go into detail how 1 + 2 = 99?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I know that I am not allowed to reply "thank you" in the comments. But how else am I supposed to confirm that my question has been answered? Sorry, I'm a bit new. But I'll get the swing of things eventually how everything works around here. 

Anyway thanks you guys! I think I understand how you can extract numbers from string. :)

Comment: @Matt - Welcome to SO :) To accept an answer, you can click the check mark on the left of it (just under the up and down arrows). That'll show that your question has been answered as well as give points to the person who answered.